# How can I prevent the lines from showing through when painting paneling?

Tags: paint

We put two coats of mud in cracks of paneling, then we primed it.
Then we put two coats of Ultra Behr paint and the lines are still coming through

Comment: do you mean drywall (aka plasterboard, Sheetrock®, gypsum wrapped in paper?) that's the only sort of "panel" you generally "mud", but it's not normally called "panelling" - and if you only applied two coats of mud, no wonder you can see the lines...

Comment: I own a house that has paneling with drywall mud on it. It's unsalvageable at this point. I'm replacing it with drywall.

Comment: You seemed to be asking two different questions, so I edited out the second one. If you have additional questions, feel free to ask them separately using the Ask Question button.

Comment: Related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2589/how-do-i-fill-in-the-grooves-in-wood-paneling-in-order-to-paint-over-it

Answer (score 1):

When you say "paneling", do you mean imitation wood paneling with grooves cut in to simulate boards?. If so, it is hard to fill those grooves. I have used Bondo auto body filler but it requires a good bit of work. Properly applied and sanded, the grooves will be invisible.

Comment: epoxy based fillers will work but might be overkill.  Try a setting-type joint compound or 'hot mud'.  "sheetrock brand" is the brand I use.

Answer (score 0):

I paint paneling frequently. The seams (lines) are more porous and tend to suck in paint and primer, causing the lines to bleed through. This is what I do for good coverage and professional look on paneling:

1) wash panels thoroughly, I use warm water with a small bit of Dawn dish soap (it cuts grease and oil).

2) use spackle on nail holes and cracks, use latex caulk on seams.

3) roll a coat of BIN 1-2-3 water base primer with a medium (1/2") nap roller, let dry 1-hour, then brush the "lines" with a second coat of the BIN.

4) roll on a coat of high quality/high solids flat interior latex paint. Apply a second coat if necessary.

I have done four jobs to date with this method and the results have been great. I do not know what you mean about "mud", are you using drywall joint compound? If so you do not need it, you should be using spackle. Always use high quality brushes and rollers, it will make all the difference.